# how to set a new property on existing records in mongoDB atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I need to add one property to all my existing users in my mongodb atlas database.

I have changed the registering process, and now, a user needs to have a 
`isValidated` set to true in order for the user to be able to login.

And the new users have it, as I create it when I create the new user, but the old ones don't have it.

So, I want that, if a user does not have a `isValidated` key, it should be added and to be set to false, but if it does, we skip that user, as it already has it.

What is the general way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.users.update({
    isValidated : {
        $exists : false
    }
},{
    $set : {
        isValidated : true
    }
},{
    multi : true
})
```

Comment: thanks! where do i do this? in the terminal? I am using atlas so i dont have mongo installed on my machine. thx! :)

Comment: You can connect to mongo atlas using Robo Mongo or Mongo compass, and run this query in that. And i guess your users collection name is `users`. Otherwise you need to replace `users` with your  collection_name, like : `db.collection_name`